# Splitting Json to multiple jsons in NIFI

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have the below json file which I want to split in NIFI

Input:

```
    [ {
  "id" : 123,
  "ticket_id" : 345,
  "events" : [ {
    "id" : 3322,
    "type" : "xyz"
  }, {
    "id" : 6675,
    "type" : "abc",
    "value" : "sample value",
    "field_name" : "subject"
  }, {
    "id" : 9988,
    "type" : "abc",
    "value" : [ "text_file", "json_file" ],
    "field_name" : "tags"
  }]
  }]
```

and my output should be 3 different jsons like below:

```
{
  "id" : 123,
  "ticket_id" : 345,
  "events.id" :3322,
  "events.type":xyz
  }

  {
  "id" : 123,
  "ticket_id" : 345,
  "events.id" :6675,
  "events.type":"abc",
  "events.value": "sample value"
  "events.field_name":"subject"
  }

  {
  "id" : 123,
  "ticket_id" : 345,
  "events.id" :9988,
  "events.type":"abc",
  "events.value": "[ "text_file", "json_file" ]"
  "events.field_name":"tags"

  }
```

I want to know can we do it using splitjson? I mean can splitjson split the json based on the array of json objects present inside the json?

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 3 different flow files, each containing one JSON object from the array, you should be able to do it with SplitJson using a JSONPath of `$` and/or `$.*`

Comment: do i need to have 2 SplitJsons with $ and $.* one after another? because with one $.* splitjson and next $.events I am getting the events are separated from id and author_id

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce function:

```
function split(json) {
    return json.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const events = item.events.map((evt) => {
            const obj = {id: item.id, ticket_id: item.ticket_id};
            for (const k in evt) {
                obj[`events.${k}`] = evt[k];
            }
            return obj;
        });
        return [...acc, ...events];
    }, []);
}

const input = [{"id":123,"ticket_id":345,"events":[{"id":3322,"type":"xyz"},{"id":6675,"type":"abc","value":"sample value","field_name":"subject"},{"id":9988,"type":"abc","value":["text_file","json_file"],"field_name":"tags"}]}];
const res = split(input);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I was wondering if we could do with the processors in Nifi